# PANDAS DataFrame operations to analyze top Server Fault tags

Tags: python, pandas, stackexchange, data-mining

I am working on learning how to do frequency analysis of Server Fault question tags to see if there is any useful data that I can glean from them. I'm storing the raw data in Bitbucket for global access, so this code will use the same dataset I am using, it's about 30Mb.

```
import pandas as pd

debiandf = pd.read_csv("https://bitbucket.org/lloydm/dataviz/raw/e84b9f9a7941d255483a81af98248b4fec8a36a8/data/LinuxSFPopularity/DebianQuestions.csv")
debiandf["CreationDate"] = pd.to_datetime(debiandf["CreationDate"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
debiandf = debiandf.set_index(["CreationDate"])

tag_df = pd.DataFrame(index=debiandf.index, data=debiandf["Tags"])
tag_df = tag_df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='CreationDate', keep='last').set_index('CreationDate')
x = tag_df["Tags"].str.extractall(r'\<(.*?)\>').unstack()
x.columns = x.columns.droplevel(0)
# column names signify the index location of the tag when extracted.
# i.e. with <ubuntu><networking><tag3> you would have [ubuntu,networking,tag3]
x.rename(columns={0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, inplace=True)

x1 = x.groupby(x.index.year)[1].apply(lambda grp: grp.value_counts().head(5))
x2 = x.groupby(x.index.year)[2].apply(lambda grp: grp.value_counts().head(5))
x3 = x.groupby(x.index.year)[3].apply(lambda grp: grp.value_counts().head(5))
x4 = x.groupby(x.index.year)[4].apply(lambda grp: grp.value_counts().head(5))
x5 = x.groupby(x.index.year)[5].apply(lambda grp: grp.value_counts().head(5))

x6 = pd.concat([x1,x2,x3], axis=1)
x6 = x6.reset_index()
x6.rename(columns={"level_0": "Year", "level_1": "Tag"}, inplace=True)
print x6
```

I'm new to using pandas and I'm learning how to do data analysis on my own so I can produce original content for [reddit](https://reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful). How can I simplify my `x.groupby` lines so I can get the top 5 value counts from every column in my `x` DataFrame?

I'm new to pandas, so if you could explain why it would be done that way, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more as to why you concat only x1,x2,x3 in x6? And maybe give us screenshot of what your data looks like and what you want it to look like at the end? The post as it is now lacks a little bit too much context (because we would need to load the dataset and run the code ourselves to see what's supposed to happen since we don't have all details)

Comment: The bitbucket link in your code 404's, so we have no clue what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go about this problem is to separate the tags, unstack them then stack them back in a way that doesn't lose creationDate values, this is done through `concat`, group the data then use `pivote_table` to rearrange the data where the periods are the columns and the tags are the index

To group the data take one of two approaches;

The first approach is to keep the creation date as a string and extract the year through `str.split`, then group the data by year and tag

```
import pandas as pd

# top n tags for each year will be displayed
n = 10
debiandf = pd.read_csv("filename")
debiandf = debiandf.reset_index().set_index(['index', "CreationDate"])
df = debiandf["Tags"].str.extractall(r'\<(.*?)\>').unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)

# take all columns in df, convert each column to a df with
# columns Year(CreationDate) and tag and stack them on top of eachother
# the resulting x will be a 2 column dataframe
x = pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame(df[x], columns=['tag']).reset_index(
    ).rename(columns={'CreationDate': 'Period'}
             ) for x in df.columns.tolist()]).drop('index', axis=1)

# change the value of year from "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" to "%Y" using split
x['Period'] = x['Period'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0])

# group values of x according to year and tag that will produce a 3 column
# ['Period','tag','count']
x6 = x.groupby(['Period', 'tag'])['tag'].agg({'count': len}).reset_index(
    # use pivote_table to reorganize the data
).pivot_table(index=['tag'], columns='Period').xs(
    # the resulting df will have the tags as index and the years as columns
    'count', axis=1, drop_level=True)

topn = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x6[col].nlargest(n)).astype(
    int).reset_index().rename(columns={
        col: 'count'}) for col in x6.columns],
    keys=x6.columns, axis=1)
print(topn[topn.columns[-6:]])
```

The second approach involves the use of `pd.tseries.resample.TimeGrouper`, to resample the date creation yearly `A` while grouping the data by year and tag

```
import pandas as pd

n = 10
debiandf = pd.read_csv("filename")
debiandf = debiandf.reset_index()
debiandf["CreationDate"] = pd.to_datetime(
    debiandf["CreationDate"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
debiandf.set_index(['index', 'CreationDate'], inplace=True)
df = debiandf["Tags"].str.extractall(r'\<(.*?)\>').unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)

# take all columns in df, convert each column to a df with
# columns Year(CreationDate) and tag and stack them on top of eachother
# the resulting x will be a 2 column dataframe
x = pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame(df[x], columns=['tag']).reset_index(
    ).rename(columns={'CreationDate': 'Period'}
             ) for x in df.columns.tolist()]).drop(
    'index', axis=1).set_index('Period')
# group the data by the tags and the creationDate resampled to yearly
x6 = x.groupby([pd.tseries.resample.TimeGrouper('A'), 'tag']
               )['tag'].agg({'count': len}).rename(
    index=lambda x: str(
        x.year) if type(x) != str else x).reset_index().pivot_table(
    index=['tag'], columns='Period').xs('count', axis=1, drop_level=True)
topn = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x6[col].nlargest(n)).astype(
    int).reset_index().rename(columns={
        col: 'count'}) for col in x6.columns],
    keys=x6.columns, axis=1)
print(topn[topn.columns[-6:]])
```

Note that the second approach is more flexible and if you decide to look at a resample rate, i.e. look at quarterly data rather than yearly, all you have to change will be the resample rates and the format of the period columns.

A sample output for both snippets is shown below, the output contains the top 10 tags for each year:

```
Period                2014                2015                2016      
                       tag count           tag count           tag count
0                   ubuntu   957        ubuntu   854        ubuntu  1010
1                    linux   428         linux   419         linux   409
2                   debian   318        debian   343        debian   339
3               apache-2.2   195    apache-2.2   120  ubuntu-14.04    91
4             ubuntu-12.04    70  ubuntu-14.04    50    apache-2.2    76
5                    nginx    59         nginx    41         nginx    67
6                    mysql    38           ssh    38    apache-2.4    46
7               networking    36    networking    37    networking    44
8                      ssh    33         mysql    29         mysql    31
9       domain-name-system    16    apache-2.4    28           ssh    27
```

Comment: The OP's code is *way* more readable...